# After spacing out

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrasal-verbs

What phrasal verb/phrase/expression should be used to describe someone who has regained control of themselves after spacing out?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about *should* be used but one *might* use; They *came to themselves* after a brief time of spacing out.